# How to find the minimum value in each row along with column name in sql/hive

Tags: sql, hive

For example :
In a table like below:

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 29 | 40 | 74 |
| 2 | 14 | 19 | 41 | 11 |
| 3 | 9 | 19 | 47 | 77 |
| 4 | 27 | 79 | 43 | 70 |

my output should return two columns like the table below:

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | MinVal | ColumnName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 29 | 40 | 74 | 10 | col1 |
| 2 | 14 | 19 | 41 | 11 | 11 | col4 |
| 3 | 9 | 19 | 47 | 77 | 9 | col1 |
| 4 | 27 | 79 | 43 | 70 | 27 | col1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `least()`:

```
select t.*,
       least(col1, col2, col3, col4) as min_val,
       (case least(col1, col2, col3, col4)
            when col1 then 'col1'
                 col2 then 'col2'
                 col3 then 'col3'
                 col4 then 'col4'
        end) as min_val_columnname
from t;
```